# glm::perspective vs gluPerspective

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I'm replacing my use of glu methods in my project with glm and I seem to have run into an odd difference that I cannot explain.  When I was using this code to set the projection matrix using gluPerspective, I get this displayed:

[image: gluPerspective version]

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(70.0f, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.0001f, 1000.0f);
```

If I switch to glm::perspective, I get this:

[image: glm::perspective version]

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(70.0f, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.0001f, 1000.0f);
glLoadMatrixf(&projectionMatrix[0][0]);
```

It's pretty clear that the object I'm rendering is taking up more of the display now with the glm version.  There are no other changes in the two versions besides swapping out gluPerspective for glm::perspective.

I'm guessing that I'm probably doing something wrong, because my understanding is that glm::perspective should be a drop in replacement for gluPerspective.  But I don't know exactly what that is at this point.

Also, the difference in orientation is because the object is being rotated in the scene.  I just ended up taking a screenshot at different times in the animation.

Comment: Note that there's not too much of a point in using glm if you're still using the deprecated matrix functions anyway. You should be using shader uniforms. In any case, check how glm stores its matrices whether they are stored row-major or column-major, and see if that matches `glLoadMatrixf`

Comment: I'm also planning to switch away from the deprecated matrix functions as well, but was just starting to replace deprecated functionality with glm when I ran into this problem. I also need to remove my use of glut as well.  As far as the order goes, glm is supposed to match up to what GL uses, since it would be a bit tough to use otherwise. The glLoadMatrix call was taken from their documentation as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

glm nowadays uses *radians* by default, while `gluPerspective()` uses degrees, so you have to use

```
glm::perspective(glm::radians(70.0f), ...);
```

to get the same result as `gluPerspective(70.0f, ...)`.

Comment: That was the problem -- I had looked at the documentation for gluPerspective, both online and in the .hpp file, but both places specified fovy in degrees and not radians.  I guess I'll send off a bug report to the developer.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where the official most recent documentation for glm is? This was my first guess, but the documentation I found showed it to be in degrees. This looks like it might be an official page: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/index.html, and it shows the use of `perspective()` with an argument in degrees right on the title page. In the API reference (http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00171.html#gac3613dcb6c6916465ad5b7ad5a786175) it says: "Specifies the field of view angle, in degrees, in the y direction. Expressed in radians." So it's ambiguous at best...

Comment: @RetoKoradi: actually, I don't know of any more recent documentation. I find the glm documentation quite unsatisfactory. It always seems to only state just the obvious which I can guess from the function name alone. In this case, the documentation seems to be flat-out  wrong, as it was not updated when they decided to switch from degrees to radians a while ago.

Comment: This kind of changes is just designed to trip people.